# Using MATLAB to save a string to a .txt file

Tags: matlab

I'm creating a text file from some data and I want to add a string as the last column of data.

```
myString = 'Test';
save('features6.txt','cuttingFeatures', 'drinkingFeatures','eatingFeatures', 'cuttingFeaturesTremors', 'drinkingFeaturesTremors', 'eatingFeaturesTremors', ' myString', '-ascii')
```

But if I assign a string to a variable it just errors out?

I'm new to MATLAB and not sure what to do here honestly.

Comment: There is a space in your string `' myString'`. Try replacing it by `'myString'`.

Comment: No, that doesn't work :/

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you wanted to do. Try `myString` without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess fprintf is what you are looking for? See the reference for examples.

http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?refresh=true